# How to achieve multiple sorting levels in Django ORM Queries

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

On the below Posts model , I need to sort the posts by both date and likes.
the results should be last 24 hr posts ,sorted by likes , then the next day posts sorted by likes , it goes on..

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    comment_text= models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date        = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    likes       = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
latest=Posts.objects.filter().order_by(-date,-likes)
```

the above query is not giving the desired results , let us say if there are two posts created at 07/06/2021 at 1 pm which has 3 likes and  another one at 1:30 pm which as 1 like.

Then the post created at 1:30 pm with 1 like comes on top instead of the post at 1 pm with 3 likes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`TruncDate` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate) to annotate the truncated date to the queryset and order using that:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate


latest = Posts.objects.annotate(truncated_date=TruncDate('date')).order_by('-truncated_date', '-likes')
```

---

> **Note**: A `DateTimeField` being named `date` is a bit weird yes? Consider renaming it.

Comment: What does annotate do here ?. And I will be passing the result to a Serialzer , hope it wont affect that in any way

Comment: @sivaperumal10000 `annotate` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) simply selects extra values in the query made to the db. No it will not affect your serializer. If you use Django version >=3.2 then you can use `alias` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#alias) as a replacement here.